# Submiting a form with jquery event doesn't work

Tags: html, jquery

I want to have a second submit button for a form where jquery will change the name attribute first and then submit this button like this:

```
<form method="post" id="myForm>
...
<button class="ui primary button tiny" type="submit" name="noredirect" id="myformsubmit"><i class="black save icon"></i>Save</button>
</form>
```

The above code just works when i click the button. But at the top of the page i have the following a tag:

```
<a href="#" id="redirectingform">
  <center><i class="big save outline icon" style="margin-right:0px !important;"></i></center>
  <div><center>Opslaan</center></div>
</a>

<!-- Below code is at the bottom of the page -->
<script>
  $('#redirectingform').click(function() {
      $('#myformsubmit').attr("name", "redirectingtoviewonly") ;
      $('#myformsubmit').submit() ;
  });
</script>
```

What I see that the jquery changes the name attribute to "redirectingtoviewonly" but it doesn't submit the button with the line `$('#myformsubmit').submit() ;`

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myformsubmit` is a button, buttons do not have a submit function.

Comment: Is there another way to submit the form with first changing the name attribute of the button?

Comment: Call submit on the form, it wont care about name attributes on the button. Why are you changing the name attribute anyway? You might want to update the question to explain what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am using django as the backend, so the django view needs to get a trigger that a different button is clicked and can redirect the to a different page after a successful submit. The name attr i can read out in the request.POST